Spring Boot 3.3: how to inject config properties into JPA AttributeConverter
How do I inject config properties into JPA AttributeConverter with Spring Boot 3.3? After upgrading from Spring Boot 3.1 to 3.3, the following converter stopped working.
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<OffsetDateTime, Timestamp> {

    MyConverter(@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone}") String dbTimeZoneName) {
        // do something with parameter
    }

    MyConverter() {
        this(null);
    }
    ...
}

With Boot 3.1, the parameterized constructor is invoked (passing the correct config value). With 3.3, I see invocations of the default constructor instead.
ChatGPT claims that

...starting with Spring Boot 3.2 and continuing into 3.3, Spring Boot changed the way it handles the creation of JPA attribute converters. Specifically, Spring now follows the JPA specification more strictly when instantiating attribute converters.


According to the JPA specification, when an AttributeConverter is used, the JPA provider (e.g., Hibernate) is responsible for instantiating it. The provider typically expects a no-args constructor because JPA does not mandate the use of dependency injection (DI) or any specific Spring-related behaviors in the creation of these converters.

Yet, I found no mention of this in either the Spring Boot 3.2 release notes or the Spring Framework release notes.
So, if ChatGPT is right, where is that documented? And...how am I expected to feed config properties into attribute converters?
P.S. Removing the default constructor works in some contexts but fails when Hibernate rather than Spring creates this bean.

This is a bit hackish, but it will work to get your spring properties into non-spring-managed objects.
Create a component that provides a static method for getting at your property values
@Component
public class ExposedPropertyResolver implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static PropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    public static String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        return propertyResolver.getProperty(propertyName);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        setPropertyResolver(context.getBean(PropertyResolver.class));
    }

    private static synchronized void setPropertyResolver(PropertyResolver propertyResolver) {
        ExposedPropertyResolver.propertyResolver = propertyResolver;
    }
}

Inside your converter, you can access the static method to get your properties.
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<OffsetDateTime, Timestamp> {
    private final String timeZone;

    MyConverter() {
        this.timeZone = ExposedPropertyResolver.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone");
    }
}

This will get you the raw property values.  If you are use SpEL, then you'll just need to implement the SpEL parser in the getProperty method.

Before I saw this proposal I did something a little less (or more?) hackish. I let MyConverter directly implement ApplicationContextAware and inside the setApplicationContext() implementation I pulled the property directly out of the context using applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("my-prop").

@MarcelStör I don't know that what you implemented will solve the issue, though, because that still requires that the Converter be a bean.  e.g., if hibernate is instantiating the converter, then your setApplicationContext method will not be invoked.

Since Hibernate 5.3 and Spring 5.1 you can try to use the appoache based on BeanContainer; here is shown a solution for inject a bean into an EntityListener, that it is managed in a similar manner of an AttributeConverter. I think that this can be a little less "hackish".

@FrancescoPoli I haven't seen the docs on this but assuming that Hibernate knows to look in the Spring context for those AttributeConverter, this would be a very clean solution
